# Moving to anchor in HTML file loaded in resources vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, vb.net-2010

I have a HTML file loaded in the resources of my app, itis a ebook that has an ancor at every chapter. i was able ot load the html file like this

`WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.Book.html`

But i cannot find any ways to jump to anchors, I tred to do it like this

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.Book.html#C1
```

But that did nto work i tryed a few other mothods but nothign worked, however i can click the links ot the chapters in the webbrowser controll.